# C | Print Boxes inside of Boxes with only for/while loops and if/else statements

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, if-statement

My code has an error that prints the boxes on separate lines instead of inside of each other. I'm assuming that the problem lies with my initial for-loop; I am unsure how to adjust the algorithm.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here is what I need:

[image]

This is the code I currently have and its output:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int boxes;

    printf("How many boxes: ");
    scanf("%d", &boxes);


    int boxSide = boxes *3 + (boxes - 1);
    int i;
    int j;

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < boxes; i++, j += 2) { 

        int row = 1;   

            while (row <= boxSide) {

                int column = 1;

                while (column <= boxSide) {

                    if ( (row == (j+1) && column >= (j+1) && column <= boxSide - (j+1)) ||
                         (row == boxSide - j && column >= (j+1) && column <= boxSide - (j+1)) ||
                         (column == (j+1) && row >= (j+1) && row <= boxSide - (j+1)) ||
                         (column == boxSide - j && row >= (j+1) && row <= boxSide - j) ) {

                    printf("#");

                    }

                    else {
                        printf(" ");
                    }

                column++;

                }

                row++;
                printf("\n");

            }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where has this been asked and not been appropriatly answered?

Comment: You will need to rethink your logic and start on the inner box when you are up to its line etc.,  not write 3 separate boxes as you are currently doing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NCurses is your friend.

It has methods for printing things at specified locations.

[Here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) is a tutorial that explains all of the methods, what NCurses is, and how to use it.

**However, to answer your question...**

This is happening because, unless you use a library like NCurses that has methods to move the cursor anywhere, `println()` (or `printf("\n")`) move the cursor to the next available line.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it, some ideas:

1) Draw to an array, and when the drawing is ready, printf content of it:

```
char table[boxSide][boxSide]; 
...
if (...) {
    table[x][y] = '#';
}
...
```

2) Move the boxes loop to the most inner loop:

```
while (row <= boxSide) {
    while (column <= boxSide) {
        char c = ' ';
        for (i = 0, j = 0; i < boxes; i++, j += 2) {                        
            if ( .... ) {
                c = '#';
            }
        }
        printf('%c', c); 
        ...
```